# How to derive (19.15) from Feynman Lectures Vol. III

Tags: derivatives

The [Feynman lectures volume 3 chapter 19](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_19.html) derives the following equation,

$$\frac{d^2g}{d\rho^2}-2\alpha\frac{dg}{d\rho}+\left(\frac{2}{\rho}+\epsilon+\alpha^2\right)g=0.\tag{9.15}$$

To do this he says to plug the following equation,

$$f(\rho)=e^{-\alpha\rho}g(\rho).\tag{9.14}$$

into this equation,

$$\frac{d^2f}{d\rho^2}=-\left(\epsilon+\frac{2}{\rho}+\right)f.\tag{9.13}$$

so after I do this I get,

$$\frac{d^2e^{-\alpha\rho}g}{d\rho^2}=-\left(\epsilon+\frac{2}{\rho}+\right)e^{-\alpha\rho}g.$$

then I use the product rule on the left hand side to get,

$$e^{-\alpha\rho}\frac{d^2g}{d\rho^2}+g\frac{d^2e^{-\alpha\rho}}{d\rho^2}=-\left(\epsilon+\frac{2}{\rho}+\right)e^{-\alpha\rho}g.$$

which then I think is,

$$e^{-\alpha\rho}\frac{d^2g}{d\rho^2}+\alpha^2ge^{-\alpha\rho}=-\left(\epsilon+\frac{2}{\rho}+\right)e^{-\alpha\rho}g.$$

which is just,

$$\frac{d^2g}{d\rho^2}+\left(\frac{2}{\rho}+\epsilon+\alpha^2\right)g=0.$$

This is the same thing as $(9.15)$ except for the $-2\alpha\frac{dg}{d\rho}$ term, so I must be missing something. Can somebody please show me where this $-2\alpha\frac{dg}{d\rho}$ term comes from?

Comment: Notice that $(fg)'' \ne f''g + fg''$.

Comment: You have to use the product rule two times, since you have a *second* derivative. You applied it as if you had a single one!

Comment: @jackychong Would you like to make that into an answer?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't think it is necessary. I will let others answer it if they want.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, more detail on the product rule that others have already pointed to in the comments:

$ \displaystyle \frac{d^2e^{-\alpha \rho}g}{d\rho^2}=\frac{d}{d\rho}\frac{de^{-\alpha \rho}g}{d\rho}= \frac{d}{d\rho}\left( -\alpha e^{-\alpha\rho}g+e^{-\alpha\rho}\frac{dg}{d\rho}\right)$

etc.